insomnia – v9.2.0 : pre request script use external library
In pre request script , i need  to user some external libraries as fs or forge
const x = require('forge') (or node-forge)  

does not work .
This
Based on what I found on the internet, I do this:

insomnia.sendRequest("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/forge/1.3.1/forge.min.js", (err, res) => {

// insomnia.globals.set("forgeJS", res.text());
if (err) {
console.log('rrrrrrrrr' + err.text());
} else {
console.log('ghghghghghgh' + err.text());
insomnia.baseEnvironment.set("forgeJS", res.text());

}
})

I have a timeout for the get whereas if I type the same url in a browser , I get a very fast response
(test with and without vpn)
(in insomnia config , i have not proxy)
how i can call this kind of lib in insomnia ?
thx for your help
how i can call this kind of lib in insomnia ?
